# Using a pipe and stdout in Python for two different purposes

Tags: python, pipe, stdout, named-pipes

How can I **pipe** a stream from a python script **without** using **stdout** for piping (on a Linux system)?

I want to pass data from a python program to a C++ program like this:

```
python3 master.py | ./slave.o
```

But I don't want to occupy the stdout because I need it for keyboard inputs.

I've also tried using a named pipe. However, this is too slow because for each data line I have to open and close the named pipe.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785148/python-popen-sending-to-process-on-stdin-receiving-on-stdout

Comment: I think it's not exact what I need, however I don't quite understand that thread.
In the meanwhile I found out that the delay was probably not by the named pipe :-)
Nevertheless thanks a lot for your help!