# Using clang-format from python script

Tags: python, clang-format

I have file whitch contains c++ code fragments. I want to make code fragments formatted. So I decide to make it with python script, but I can't find any examples.
I Know how to find code fragment in file, but I dont understand how to format this fragment with clang-format.
For example I have string

```
str = "if(i == 0){return;}"
```

How can I format it with clang-format?

In clang-format help I found:

**If no arguments are specified, it formats the code from standard input
and writes the result to the standard output.**

How can I use this to format code fragment from script?

---

Update: after reading
[Python Popen sending to process on stdin, receiving on stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785148/python-popen-sending-to-process-on-stdin-receiving-on-stdout)
I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

unformattedCode = 'void function(){}'

proc = subprocess.Popen('clang-format-12',stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(unformattedCode.encode())
proc.stdin.close()
formattedCode = proc.stdout.read().decode()
print(formattedCode)
```

The main problem now that I have to close stdio stream after each write operation, to get formatted string. Without closing stdio there is no any data in stdout.
As I have to process a lot of code fragments it is non-optimal to run new subprocess for each code fragment and then close it.

Comment: Start clang-format as subprocess, write code fragment to stdin of the subprocess, read formatted code fragment from stdout of the subprocess. Do I understand correctly that your question is how to start a subprocess from Python and how to access its stdin/stdout?

Comment: yes. If you can show me any relevant example, it will be great.